# How do you convert a document in UML 1.3 - XMI 1.1 format to UML 2.1 XMI?

Tags: uml, xmi, powerdesigner

I am trying to convert a file exported from PowerDesigner in the UML 1.3 - XMI 1.1 format to the UML 2.1 XMI Interchange Model from Rational Software Architect.  How can I do this?

Comment: I done an analysis and find couple more on the internet that proves that XMI is not supported accross the tools although each claims to do so. I would like to know how did you solve the problem.

Comment: I didn't solve it, I use PowerDesigner for now.

Answer (score 3):

It can be worth to give a try to the [XMI file converter](http://www.baptisteautin.com/projets-personnels/php_uml/convertisseur-de-fichier-xmi/lang/en/) its web based using Php.

Answer (score 1):

If RSA won't import XMI 1.1 then you'll need to find another tool that will. Enterprise Architect by Sparx Systems can import XMI 1.1 and can write XMI 2.1. You can get a free 30 day trial from their website at http://www.sparxsystems.com. Be warned though that there are different dialects of XMI, so you may need to try a variety of tools and see which one works best. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The XMI, though a standard, is not implemented unifromly across tools. Altova UModel is the closest thing to the XMI standard. However, it is costly, so you can work with [EA](http://www.sparxsystems.com)
It enables you to import XMI of different versions and also XMI into different versions, but some of your data may get lost.

The best way to do a translation from XMI 1.3 to XMI 2.1 is actually tranlating it through XSLT as both XMI1.3 and XMI2.1 are XML formats only.

Answer (score 0):

I found that XMI v1.3 exported models from Power Designer v10 (v12 also does the same if I don't recall bad) does not export any UML diagram (read: class, activities, use case diagrams) so no transformation can solve the problem then, since there is no data about the diagrams at all.

Any clues about Power Designer new releases, updates, fixes, patches ?