# UML tool to work both with UML 2 and UML 1.x

Tags: uml

I have a rather simple UML project in StarUML (UML 1.3) and now I need to convert it to UML 2.0 to work with it in Eclipse.

Are there any tools that can me to convert UML 1.x to UML 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to export the UML Project in XMI, then you can use a tool to convert it to another version.

This question here describes how to convert  1.1 to 2.1
[How to convert from UML 1.3 - XMI 1.1 to UML 2.1 XMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829791/how-to-convert-from-uml-1-3-xmi-1-1-to-uml-2-1-xmi)

---

Here is a list of UML Tools and their features
[List of Unified Modeling Language tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_tools)